# what is the difference between submodule add and init?

Tags: git

Really, what is the difference between `submodule add` and `submodule init`? Or more precisely when would you want to use one without the other?

Answer (score 5):

You use `git submodule add` when you yourself want to add a new submodule to a project.

You use `git submodule init` when you clone a project that has submodules, or when someone else has added a submodule to a project.

Comment: Great answer. But then when would you `git submodule update`?

Answer (score 3):

Add is when you want to import another git repository to your current git repository (called the "superproject"). To perform that it records in the `.gitmodules` the path to the repository, thus adding it to the index.

Submodule init will create already-existing submodules recorded in the index. This is achieved configuring the paths found in the index in git.

Add:

> Add the given repository as a submodule at the given path to the changeset to be committed next to the current project: the current
>   project is termed the "superproject".

Init:

> Initialize the submodules recorded in the index (which were added
>    and committed elsewhere) by copying submodule names and urls from `.gitmodules` to `.git/config`.

**Therefore init checks out the submodules already recorded in the index that where previously added with**

```
git submodule add my_sub_project directory_in_superproject
```

Typically when cloning the superproject you would do:

```
git clone superproj
```

within the project then:

```
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: The meaning of the init is still left as vague as before, quoting the docs just for repeating them is distracting... Why does that copying need to take place in git? what would occur if `init` is skipped? what's the rational of having two separate steps for placing a submodule in a repository?

Comment: `.gitmodules` is how you share submodules with others. If you clone a repo with submodules, take a look in `.git/config` - it has no idea about the submodules. `git submodule init` imports the submodules from the `.gitmodules` file into your local repository.

Comment: @matt add just places the entries , i.e. pointers , for submodules. The init brings thoses entries to your local repository. Skipping init will not allow you to use the submodule ( i.e. bring code , commit , etc ) . For each submodule there is a "gitlink tree entry" , a logical name needs to be assigned, which is held in .gitmodules. I guess there could be a one step process, but this way you have more flexibility, and clarity. However, how would you go about initializing ( i.e. checking out ) already existing submodules?